# How do I query which issues have referred to another?

Tags: github, github-api

If someone mentions a Github issue (A) in another Github issue (B), Github will add a crossreference in B referring back to A:

[image: Screenshot of an example]

Is it possible for me to query for all references to a specific issue (for example, B) using the Github API?

Answer (score 0):

The [issue timeline API](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/timeline/) supports this. The event type to look for is "cross-referenced".